# Spammers in my Magento blog comment section!

Tags: blog, spam, magento, spam-prevention, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent spam on sites which I control?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control)

I have a blog extension installed on my Magento website. But I regularly receive spam comments on the blog. To help fight against automated and manual spam comments on the blog I have enabled a Captcha service.  But even with the Captcha service running the site still receives spam, is there a more effective method to avoid spam?

Comment: @Paulmorriss : My question is regarding Blog in Magento, the duplicate you have mentioned is a General question for blogs..

Comment: Some (but not all) of those solutions should work with Magento.

Comment: @balanv Sorry we can't be more specific, this subject comes up so frequently that we end up rehashing the same answers over again. There is a decent thread on the subject at magento commerce that might help you out more. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18093/

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question, it's been asked so often that we've added a [community wiki answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control) that summarizes the best methods.