# Moderator with no power to fix spam bot issue

Tags: spam-prevention, phpbb, botattack, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent spam on sites which I control?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control)

I think this is the correct site to post this.

So I'm a **moderator** (not administrator) on anddev.org and it's completely infested with spam bots, just as fast as I ban them, more post.

I'm sure they can sign up faster than I can ban them.

There is a two stage first post sign up validation that they have clearly got around.

I'd also like to delete all posts by that user when they are banned. (which I can't see an option for)

Is there anything I can do?

*EDIT*

This was closed for the wrong reasons:

**I'm just a moderator not an administrator** I can't do any of the things in that wikipost. I wanted to know what I can do as a Mod, or how I can find more options, or even what the software is I am moderating!

Comment: Cheers for closing. I DON'T control any of the things written in that wiki post. But cheers for closing a question without reading it thoroughly.

Comment: If you're just a mod then you need to contact the site admins, not post here.

Comment: Right, if that's all I can do thanks. I'll bug them again it's just they've gone AWOL

Comment: @Blundell as a moderator, the only thing you can do is ban spambots. If you want to do anything else, you need to contact the admins and ask them to implement some of the solutions specified in this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control

Comment: If the powers that be have abandoned you then you've lost your support. It's no surprise you're having a hard time keeping up with the spammers. You've basically been set up to fail.

Comment: Well at least I know now I can't do anything without upping my privileges to Administrator, so I'll sit an wait!