# Does anyone run a site with Pligg? What is the most effective way to stop spam sign ups?

Tags: spam, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent spam on sites which I control?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control)

Specifically trying to combat things like this! http://www.autopliggdotcom  (didnt want to give them a link!)

Comment: @toomanyairmiles you can't apply advices from that question to pligg.

Comment: I had 2 sites with pligg and shut them down because of spam. Even with a ReCaptcha...

Answer (score 2):

The problem with coming up with a solution is that if it is posted on the internet, autopligg will just find a way around it.  To fight the spam I have had to hack Pligg and come up with custom methods to keeping spam at bay and even at that, spammers still find a way around my defenses.  My suggestion to you is to keep up-to-date on the latest techniques in spam prevention and create a custom anti-spam system unique to your installation of Pligg.  Then change it up every so often to keep the spammers guessing.  Some of the techniques that I use are capcha, nonces, and akismet.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to stop spam sign ups with Pligg is to **disable signups**. Because, to be fair, I think, Pligg is just a flawed platform :/

But if you do have some financial returns from your pligg, then:

- Akismet helps (to bounce off blatant unsophisticated spam),
- unique custom registration helps (for a week or so),
- requiring working facebook / twitter / g+ account helps,
- moderation helps.
- text captcha is almost useless.
- non-conventional captchas confuse normal users more that spammers.